# How to show items in a list view only when the sequence is the same

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

I want to display "best" below only those comments that match the sequence of the top three best comments.

CommentAdapter

```
   for (GoodsComment num : list) {
            if (item.getSeq() == num.getSeq()) {
                holder.txtBest.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            } else {
                holder.txtBest.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        }
```

This code works but only one

Comment: please post your complete commentAdapter code

Comment: https://github.com/eggham0518/forQuestion/blob/master/GoodsCommentAdapter.java

Comment: I think it'll work if I make a few modifications. ㅜㅜ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are doing this inside the adapter, you should not use the for loop. Create an array containing sequence numbers of best comments and put it as a variable in the adapter.

Then in the adapter, getView() (for Listview) or bindView() (for RecyclerView) check if the sequence number is in the array you created earlier.

This should show the "best" flag in all the matching rows.

Comment: Thank you, sir. Now I understand what's wrong structurally. But I don't know where and how to declare sequence variable in adapter.

Answer (score 0):

try to use integer flag and each time increment flag then check if flag = 3 or not

Answer (score 0):

Are you updating the list item **item** every time after the for loop?